# Huawei dongle keeps on disconnecting when idle. How do I stop this?

Tags: 12.04, mobile-broadband, huawei

I have a Huawei E172 USB dongle that works perfectly with Precise. However it keeps on disconnecting the internet connection when I'm not doing anything that requires internet connection. I think it has to do with `Powertop tunables`. I have turned so many things off in this section. Here is the list of the things I turned off:

[image: Here is the screenshot of the tunable section in Powertop]

Comment: I think that you enabled autosuspend for USB while relying on USB for your internet connection :-) I don't use powertop, because I lack a deep understanding of what it actually does.

Comment: I have now turned off autosuspend for anything 'USB' related to see if that will stop this. I'll report back if this is successful

Comment: Indeed not turning things related to 'USB' solves the issue of disconnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try changing the state of your mobile broadband from the `Tunables` tab.

As the Powertop web site doesn't have any useful documentation, I was unable to find any concrete answers. However, you can have a look at the website: http://www.lesswatts.org/projects/powertop/

Some more links:

- http://www.admin-magazine.com/Articles/PowerTOP

Comment: You are so right about the lack of documentation with regards to Powertop

Answer (score 1):

A temporary solution would be to prevent the internet connection from idling with a simple script.
Create file `/etc/cron.d/ping`

```
# /etc/cron.d/ping
# ping every one minute
* * * * * nobody ping -c 1 -W 10 -q www.google.com >/dev/null 2>&1
```